# netCDF import problem in QGIS (XY issue)

Tags: qgis-2, netcdf, data-management

I working with a netCDF file related to precipitation over time in QGIS. When I import the file, QGIS reads the data indicating y-coordinate, instead of timestep, as the dynamic dimension to associate raster values with.

When I use netCDF browser to select slices of the data, what I am getting is bands plotting x-coordinate and time, separated for each value of the y-coordinate.

What I would like to get is bands plotting precipitation for each x and y coordinate separated for each value of time.

Is there a way to change which dimensions QGIS uses for spatial reference for a netCDF file, either during importation or afterwards?

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html "There is no universal way of storing georeferencing in NetCDF files" - some tricks there might help, or at least help to convert to something QGIS can read directly, but the output of `gdalinfo` on your file would help your question enormously.